# How to append a dynamic div in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
.directive('mydirective', [function($scope, $document,windowService) {
return{
    link : function(scope,element,attars){
        --- Some more code —--

        var containers = $('.container’);
        containers.bind('click', function(event) {
            var elem = event.currentTarget;
            elem.append('<div>test</div>’); //Appending is failing
        });
    }
}]);

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'elem.append('<div>test</div>')')
```

I am just starting off with AngularJS and stuck with the above issue, I am trying to append a div to the container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this

```
containers.bind('click', function (event) {
        var elem = event.currentTarget;
        $(elem).append('<div>test</div>’); //Appending should work
}
```

as `elem` can be the HTML input object you have to convert it into jQuery object to use `.append()` method of jQuery! so wrap your `elem` variable arround `$()`. It should work

Answer (score 0):

Better to use this. Removes dependency to JQuery as Angular core only use JQLite. It is basically the same thing that happens.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

```
containers.bind('click', function (event) {
        var elem = event.currentTarget;
        angular.element(elem).append('<div>test</div>’); //Appending should work
}
```