# AngularJS: dynamically appending child div from directive

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to append a div from directive link function but nothing happen.

here is small code snippet. hence i am new in angular. so not being able to capture the fault in code. please tell me where i made the mistake.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('busyBox',function(){
     return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function(){
            if(attrs.id=='btnadd')
            {
               element.parent().parent().find('.parent').append('<div>Some text</div>')
                //element.closest('.parent').append('<div class="child">child</div>')
              //angular.element(document).find('.parent').append('<div class="child">child</div>');
            }
            else if(attrs.id=='btnDel')
            {
                alert('clicked del btn');
            }
          }); 

        }
        }
})
```

jsfiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/tridip/4o1zkbj1/3/

Comment: where a div will be appended?

Comment: the child div will be appended to parent div which has parent css class. please see my jsfiddle then you can understand what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: You're trying to use Angular as if it was jQuery. Use templating. Have a model. Modify the model, and have the template automatically add a new div automatically, thanks to ng-repeat. You're missing the whole point of Angular.

Comment: i follow this url https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348949/5314244 they show we can add div using jqlite this way

Comment: They're missing the point, too.

Comment: @MonojitSarkar Just because you can do something does not mean you should...

Comment: Here's how you should do it: http://plnkr.co/edit/MMtJddtDNFZoPSebsmKq?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `querySelector`.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.directive('busyBox',function(){
     return  {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.on('click', function(){
            if(attrs.id=='btnadd')
            {
         
              var divElement = angular.element(document.querySelector('.parent')).append('<div class="child">Some text</div>');
        //     console.log(divElement);
             //  element.parent().find('.parent').append('<div>Some text</div>')
             //element.closest('.parent').append('<div class="child">child</div>')
              //angular.element(document).find('.parent').append('<div class="child">child</div>');
            }
            else if(attrs.id=='btnDel')
            {
            document.body.querySelector('.child').remove();
           //    m.removeChild(m.firstChild);
            }
          }); 
          
        }
        }
})
```

```css
.parent { 
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px; 
  background-color:red;
  position: relative;
}

.child {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position: absolute
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<div id="dvParent" class="parent">parent div
    
</div>
<br>
<button id="btnadd" busy-box>Add Div</button>
<button id="btnDel" busy-box>Remove Div</button>
</div>
```

Comment: already i did it last day but forgot to update my post. thanks for your answer. one request that can you vote up for my this question because my reputation is very low on this site. i marked your answer.

Comment: i have one question that directive can access dom element because element is injected in link function....so why you use angular.element() instead of element ? please discuss the reason. thanks

Comment: oh ok. angular.element is an alias for the jQuery function and it's look any where and do any change, element is refer current directive. You need to append outside of directive so I used angular.element, Inside directive element means element is enough.

Comment: Angular element is a alias of which jquery function?